# How to convert int timestamp to DateTime in json_serializable flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter

How can I convert an integer timestamp to Datetime.

**Sample Code:**

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);    
}
```

How do I convert dateOfBirth integer timeStamp to DateTime?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To convert an `int` timestamp to `DateTime`, you need to pass a static method that
    returns a `DateTime` result to the `fromJson` parameter in the @JsonKey annotation.

This code solves the problem and allows the convertion.

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
    class Person {
      final String firstName;
      final String lastName;
      @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJson, toJson: _toJson)
      final DateTime dateOfBirth;
      Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
      factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);

      static DateTime _fromJson(int int) => DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int);
      static int _toJson(DateTime time) => time.millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    }
```

usage

```
Person person = Person.fromJson(json.decode('{"firstName":"Ada", "lastName":"Amaka", "dateOfBirth": 1553456553132 }'));
```

Comment: It didn't work for me in my case data from firebase, Has the timestamp value to datetime(local) failed.

Answer (score 9):

I use this:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Person {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp)
  DateTime dateOfBirth;
 
  ...
}

DateTime dateTimeFromTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
  return timestamp == null ? null : timestamp.toDate();
}
```