# Flutter json_serializable error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Im having the problem above, I understand that in my data some things are null for example the leistungData from Diesel doesn't contain anything, so the title is null:

```
                "title":"Benzin",
                "leistungData":[
                   {
                      "title":"240 PS"
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "title":"Diesel",
                "leistungData":[
                   
                ]
             },
```

So I get that I get the  'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'. But how can I change my code below so that I can keep this Json structure?

```
    import 'leistungData.dart';


part 'treibstoffData.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class TreibstoffData {
  final String title;
  final List <LeistungData> leistungData;

  TreibstoffData(this.title, this.leistungData);

  factory TreibstoffData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  => _$TreibstoffDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TreibstoffDataToJson(this);
}
```

& here the LeistungData:

```
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'unterscheidungsData.dart';

part 'leistungData.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class LeistungData {
  final String title;

  LeistungData(this.title);

  factory LeistungData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  => _$LeistungDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LeistungDataToJson(this);
}
```

I hope I was clear and didn't forget anything, just write to me if Im missing something

Comment: Can you show TreibstoffDataFromJson method too?

Comment: think we fixed it now, but appreciate your will )

Comment: the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423975/7198006

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, although the other one worked for me, I like the default value approach, because you then don't have to use the ? & ! Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to nullable list.

replace final `List <LeistungData> leistungData;` with `final List <LeistungData>? leistungData;`
also try `final String? title ;`
let me know if it fails to solve the error.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, still get the same error, should I send you the full code?

Comment: sure, then i will be able to check

Comment: btw are you using freezed,? also can you share full json file

Comment: I kinda fixed it now, changed the  final String title; part also to  final String? title; I will test further and keep you updated if it works as intended, maybe I will discover a problem during testing

Comment: can you add the final String? title in your answer, will mark it then as solved, or do you see a potential problem with that solution?

Comment: Thank you ..... if you fail after update question with full json and other parts. i will test on my side